# Processing selected row in C# ListView

Tags: listview

I have a ListView that has 2 columns. I have the SelectedIndexChanged set to listView1_SelectedIndexChanged. I have the Click event set to listView1_Row_Click. In the below code, when I click on a row, the if (slected != null) statement always defaults to catch. During debug, the selected variable is always empty.

```
    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //get the selected item
            BenefitCode selected = (BenefitCode)listView1.SelectedItems;
            if (selected != null)
            {
                //display the code
                tbBenCode.Text = selected.Code.ToUpper();
                benMethod.Text = selected.ben_Method.ToUpper();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AddMsg("some kind of error listView1_selectedindexchanged");
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            //AddMsg("Err: (listView1_SelectedIndexChanged) " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void listView1_Row_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

        BenefitCode selected = (BenefitCode)listView1.SelectedItems;
        if (selected != null)
        {
            //display the code
            tbBenCode.Text = selected.Code.ToUpper();
            benMethod.Text = selected.ben_Method.ToUpper();

        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AddMsg("some kind of error listView1_Row_Click");
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I've debugged the code and I can see the BenefitCode selected line always failed. I want to see the if selected the listview items code and ben_method into the text boxes to be modified